# How can I configure `Authorised Domains` when deploying oidc provider to gcp via terraform?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I am deploying OIDC provider to GCP via terraform. I am using this doc as instruction to set it up:
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/identity_platform_default_supported_idp_config

It works and I am able to deploy an identity to GCP identity platform. The configuration looks like below:

```
resource "google_identity_platform_default_supported_idp_config" "idp_config" {
  enabled       = true
  idp_id        = "playgames.google.com"
  client_id     = "client-id"
  client_secret = "secret"
}
```

The problem I have is that I can't find where I can add `Authorised Domains`. When I open this identity on GCP console, I can add the domain on the right panel like below screenshot. But how can I configure them via terraform?

[image]

Comment: did you find how to add authorized domains?

Comment: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/identity_platform_config#authorized_domains